# Lotus Notes Emails Scroll Very Slowly

Tags: email, lotus-notes, scrolling

When viewing some emails in Lotus Notes 8 the email scrolls very slowly when scrolled with the mouse wheel.  Scrolling with the mouse wheel works fine other times, and there are no problems at all using it with other applications.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Stop using Lotus Notes.  :-)

Comment: Nothing would please me more, but unfortunately it's not my decision to make. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to tell you but **there is no fix** for this.

Notes is inherently broken in the sense that it doesn't act or work like a Windows application. While it does do most things in a way that is familiar, some things are just not what you expect. It has been this way for every version since dawn; I don't see any chance of it changing for the better this century.

Specifically, scrolling a window that contains text requires much more mouse-wheel-turning than the same number of lines in e.g. MS Word or Notepad. If the Notes window contains an image, it will become even slower/harder to scroll for as long as the image is partially visible.

Notes just is that way. **Accept it** since none of us can change it.

Comment: Asking an honest question about an application is hardly crying.  I'll accept the answer (at least until a better one is posted), but I'm down-voting your response snide remark.

Comment: Apologies!! I certainly didn't mean to direct that against *you*. I meant it like the saying *crying over spilled milk.* I always try to write short and precise answers, but I never mean to hurt. I've removed that remark now.

Comment: BTW, I'm a fellow victim of Notes for the past 10 years...

Comment: I understand.  Thank you for the feedback, anyways.